# Problem in Kile editor so LaTeX file is not running

Tags: formatting, templates

EDITED post:

In the following Template http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\setstretch{1.3} % Line spacing of 1.3

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{} % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage} % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{} % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy} % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % New command to make the lines in the title page

% PDF meta-data
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\textsc{\LARGE \univname}\\[1.5cm] % University name
\textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{\authornames} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\href{http://www.jamessmith.com}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\vfill
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DECLARATION PAGE
%   Your institution may give you a different text to place here
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\Declaration{

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

I, \authornames, declare that this thesis titled, '\ttitle' and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:

\begin{itemize} 
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution, this has been clearly stated.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] I have acknowledged all main sources of help.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others, I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.\\
\end{itemize}

Signed:\\
\rule[1em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature

Date:\\
\rule[1em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date
}

\clearpage % Start a new page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUOTATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers or footers for the following pages

\null\vfill % Add some space to move the quote down the page a bit

\textit{``Thanks to my solid academic training, today I can write hundreds of words on virtually any topic without possessing a shred of information, which is how I got a good job in journalism."}

\begin{flushright}
Dave Barry
\end{flushright}

\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\null % Add some space at the bottom to position the quote just right

\clearpage % Start a new page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\addtotoc{Abstract} % Add the "Abstract" page entry to the Contents

\abstract{\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots
}
\end{document}
```

In the abstract page it seems that the university and author name are automatically placed.

I think they referred the university name here

```
\textsc{\LARGE \univname}\\[1.5cm] % University name
\textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type
```

but I have not got that how university name appeared automatically on the abstract section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not exactly sure what your question is, as you don't really say, so I'm answering what I *think* your question is.)

The class file defines a series of commands that holds the title of the thesis (`\ttitle`), the author name (`\authornames`), the supervisor name (`\supname`), the university name (`\univname`), and perhaps others. If you look in the abstract you'll find these commands used:

```
I, \authornames, declare that this thesis titled, '\ttitle' and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:
```

You can redefine them with

```
\renewcommand\CommandName{Your own definition}
```

For example:

```
\renewcommand\ttitle{My lovely thesis}
\renewcommand\authornames{Your Name}
\renewcommand\supname{Your supervisor's name}
\renewcommand\univname{University of Stuff}
```

Add these to the preamble (before `\begin{document}`).