# Problem in .cls file

Tags: formatting

```
! LaTeX Error: File `Thesis.cls' not found.
```

I am using Kile editor. If the above error appeared in the log file then how to correct it?

Comment: Did you mean to use `thesis.cls` (note the lowercase `T`)?

Comment: I have copied  the error from the log file.

Comment: Did the answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130050/thesis-running-problem-in-kile help?

Comment: I want to solve this without using windows.

Comment: @Jubobs Same basic problem, different class file, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155004/problem-in-kile-editor-so-latex-file-is-not-running#comment354419_155004